# How can I dynamically create objects by a given string name?

Tags: javascript, jointjs

I am trying to create object from given string. The string value should be the name of the new object. I created a root object and the create the subsequent objects by give in a string name and clone from the root object.

I am using jointJs.

Here is the root object

```
var lvl0 = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
    position: { x: 100, y: 30 },
    size: { width: 100, height: 30 },
    attrs: { rect: { fill: '#31d0c6', stroke: 'none',  filter: { name: 'dropShadow',  args: { dx: 3, dy: 6, blur: 3, color: '#333333' }} }, 
             text: { text: 'lvl0', fill: '#ffffff' }, 
             style: { 'text-shadow': '1px 0 1px #333333' }  }

});
```

Then the function that clones the root object and assign a given name to the new object.

```
function add_cell(parent, child, lvl, color) {
  if (lvl === 0)
  { var child = parent.clone().translate(0, 0).attr('text/text', child);  }
  else { var child = parent.clone().translate(200, 0).attr('text/text', child).attr('rect/fill', color); }
  graph.addCell(child);
  if (lvl != 0) {  createLink(parent, child).set(createLabel('0,N     1,1')); }
}
```

Here is the calling code.

```
var lst = [ { "parent": "lvl0", "child": "dept", "lvl": 0, "color": "green" }, { "parent": "dept", "child": "empl", "lvl": 1, "color": "yellow" } ];
for (var i = 0; i < lst.length; i++) {
  add_cell (window[lst[i].parent], lst[i].child, lst[i].lvl, lst[i].color);
}
```

The first clone is successful because the object **lvl0** being clone is an existing object. But the second clone will fail because object **dept** does not exist. Instead the **child** variable is overwritten to a cloned object. I basically need to rename the cloned object from **child** to **dept**. How can I do this?

Thanks,

Comment: Question is not clear